# Only order mails are not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

Order related mails are not working. But subscription mails are working. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried any SMTP modules?

Comment: Yes I tried. But not working. Issue is only for order related mails.

Comment: Have you checked your cron jobs. Also please check cron logs in db

Comment: which is the job code for this?

Comment: Please check this one sales_send_order_emails

Comment: I fixed this issue. I corrected  the cron issues

Answer (score 1):

Please check your cron jobs. If the cron jobs are working check the cron status for `sales_send_order_emails` in `cron_schedule` table. It might contain some useful information for you to debug.

Comment: Where we can find this to check? Me too have this issue

Comment: check in database. There is one table for cron status

Comment: Check your cron_schedule table in database. It will have a job_code sales_send_order_emails. Please check there

Comment: @soofz,  https://prnt.sc/nrbh0j

Comment: Refer this: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/

Comment: Try to restart cron. I restarted cron and installed mageplaza smtp plugin. Then it worked.